# React native how to place a view bottom center

Tags: react-native

[image][image]

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 4,
          backgroundColor: '#0096FF',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          paddingHorizontal: '5%',
        }}>
        <Text style={{color: '#e2ffff', fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'Poppins'}}>
          Sales-Today
        </Text>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <Text
            style={{
              color: 'white',
              fontSize: 25,
              fontFamily: 'Poppins-SemiBold',
            }}>
            ₹ 2,945769.34
          </Text>
          <Feather
            name="refresh-cw"
            size={20}
            color="#bde2ff"
            style={{alignSelf: 'center', marginLeft: '3%'}}
          />
        </View>
        <View
          style={[
            {
              borderWidth: 4,
              borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
              height: 48,
              width: 48,
              borderRadius: 8,
              backgroundColor: '#6638f0',
              position: 'absolute',
              bottom: 0,
              zIndex: 1,
              alignSelf: 'center',
            },
           
          ]}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={{flex: 6, backgroundColor: 'white'}}></View>
    </View>
```

I want to create a white card at the center of the parent view in my react native application.But the view is not centered at the bottom of first view.Help me to overlay the cardview with parent view.

Comment: In the main view just add `justifyContent: 'center',` and `alignItem: 'center'`.

Comment: no its not working

Comment: i have added to the view for which i have given flex:4

Comment: can you please provide more info and full ss

Comment: please check my above code

Comment: I think your mentioned code and image are different.

Comment: Working Example: https://snack.expo.dev/@msbot01/smart-cereal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Example: snack.expo.dev/@msbot01/smart-cereal

```
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { SafeAreaView, Text, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor:'green'}}>
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row', backgroundColor:'yellow', width:'90%',  justifyContent:'space-between', alignItems:'center', position:'absolute', top:150, zIndex:10, marginLeft:'5%', marginRight:'5%', height:100, padding:10, borderRadius:10}}>
        <View
          style={{
              borderWidth: 4,
              borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
              height: 48,
              width: 48,
              borderRadius: 8,
              backgroundColor: 'blue',
              bottom: 0,
              zIndex: 1,
              alignSelf: 'center',
            }}
        />
        <View
          style={{
              borderWidth: 4,
              borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
              height: 48,
              width: 48,
              borderRadius: 8,
              backgroundColor: 'blue',
              
              bottom: 0,
              zIndex: 1,
              alignSelf: 'center',
            }}
        />
        <View
          style={{
              borderWidth: 4,
              borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
              height: 48,
              width: 48,
              borderRadius: 8,
              backgroundColor: 'blue',
              
              bottom: 0,
              zIndex: 1,
              alignSelf: 'center',
            }}
        />
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: '#0096FF',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          paddingHorizontal: '5%',
          height:200,
          marginBottom:75
        }}>
        <Text style={{color: '#e2ffff', fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'Poppins'}}>
          Sales-Today
        </Text>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <Text
            style={{
              color: 'white',
              fontSize: 25,
              fontFamily: 'Poppins-SemiBold',
            }}>
            ₹ 2,945769.34
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>

      <Text>New Section</Text>
      
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```